# Redundant MySQL Index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

```
Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
 Edit    Drop   PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  TickerID    23200   A       
Timestamp   13897209    A   
 Edit    Drop   TickerID    BTREE   No  No  TickerID    11737   A       
 Edit    Drop   Timestamp   BTREE   No  No  Timestamp   18  A       

~99,424,209 InnoDB  utf8_general_ci 5.1 GiB
```

OK before I try to "optimize" this DB by deleting unneeded indexes I thought I'd ask here.  This table gets hit a lot so I want to speed up insert performance.  I read 5 articles on the net that seem to indicate that the single index on TickerID is redundant because the multiple index (TickerID,Timestamp) will be used if I ever run a query on just tickerID.

Occasionally, I will like to do EOD reporting, so that I might just do something like `SELECT * WHERE Timestamp > Today() - 1 day` or something like that.  Do I need the timestamp index as well?

Comment: are ticketids sequential, or they are uuids? What are the datatypes of the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This index on `tickerId, timestamp` can be used by all queries which can use an index on `tickerId` only.

However, for a query like that:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   Timestamp > Today() - 1
```

an index on `(tickerId, timestamp`) will not be used, since there is no equality filter on `tickerId`.

For this query, you should create an index on `timestamp` only or rewrite thу query:

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT tickerId
        FROM    mytable
        ) md
JOIN    mytable m
ON      m.tickerId = md.tickerId
        AND m.timestamp > TODAY() - 1
```

However, the latter query is less efficient, especially if you have lots of distinct values in `tickerId`.

Comment: @user: you welcome. Please mark my answer (and other good answers to all the questions you have asked) as accepted, this would encourage people to help you.